# Python 3.7 Device or resource busy: '.nfs000000000000ad1e000047d3'

Tags: python, linux, pytorch

I have a python script that I run on a remote Linux server to train a CNN in pytorch .
In the last few days I got this error when I run the script :

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 265, in _run_finalizers
    finalizer()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 189, in __call__
    res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/user/virtualenvs/classifier/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 491, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/home/user/virtualenvs/classifier/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 449, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/user/virtualenvs/classifier/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 447, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(entry.name, dir_fd=topfd)
OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '.nfs000000000000ad1e000047d3'
```

I also found it strange that after running the Python script, a lot of pymp* files were created in the script folder, which was not the case a week ago.
thanks in advance for your help.
**I run my code on a virtual enviroment**

Comment: The remote filesystem does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

it is one of the below issues.

- hardware issue
- partition on which your virtual environment is created is a corrupted
  partition.
- partition is not configured or mounted properly. (mount umount it)
- check the number of open files with the `lsof` command
- with `fuser` command you will list which process is using a file or
  files within a mount.

Comment: the problem was that I didn't have enough space in the home directory where the code runs. I moved the code to another place where there is enough space and it worked and the issue was solved.

Comment: Yes . that is the first level of troubleshooting.